# issues coming under XML description

Tags: c#, xml

can you tell me whats going on here actually,can u explain that structure.

here how they are generating these numbers `<ID>6b25ad0c-8223-49e7-ad94-a132127692c3</ID>`

`<Blank>632918408948995524</Blank>`   What is `<LeafDataSchema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/LeafDataSchema.xsd">`

then Why we need UUID,,how it is generating??

Comment: It's an XML document that contains data. It has a root element, two children of the root, and many grandchildren. Looks like it might be the result of a JAXB transformation. What do you really want to know?

Comment: Going to tempuri.org, I see that it's an example domain used for ASP.Net namespaces. So ignore my comment about JAXB, and substitute whatever serialization mechanisms .Net supports.

Comment: SpoDataSchema.xsd i found this in project containg so many tables just like SQL tables every table they are describing in this XML as its node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`6b25ad0c-8223-49e7-ad94-a132127692c3` is a example of a [UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) - many language frameworks offer library functions to generate them.

Sometimes also called GUID (Globally Unique Identifier)

Comment: In string representation form (actually a 128bit number)

Comment: then Why we need UUID,,how it is generating

Comment: okey but how they are generating in this xml file,,here <SpoDataSchema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SpoDataSchema.xsd"> i found 
SpoDataSchema.xsd in my project,,all tables in that xml file is discribed in node of the xml file

Comment: @peter - There are literally dozens of ways this file could have been generated. Without more information from you we cannot help any more than we have.

Answer (score 2):

The `xmlns` attribute defines the default namespace that unadorned elements belong to.

See:-  http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp